# How can i remove this console from my page?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Am testing my webpage on firefox and everything is looking fine, but when i run my page on IE or chrome a section with

**Clear ReCSS console DOM Object Close**

What is it and how can i remove it?

Answer (score 4):

This one had me going also for a while. If you are utilising the DOJO framework then you need to turn Debug=false as this is the firebug-lite console that is shipped with it! If not it is still the Firebug-lite console. Firebug-lite will not show on Firefox as it has the full Firebug hence why it shows up on other browers.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have malformed html that Firefox is handling differently than IE and Chrome.  Make sure you have matching opening and closing tags throughout!

If you post the html in question, we might be able to help a bit more...